# Conversion of an image as a String into byte[] and then back into a Base64 encoded String

Tags: java, jsf, type-conversion

I already researched a whole lot and there exists much information on the single steps of what I try to do, but since I do not know which part of the procedure I am not getting right I decided to describe my whole problem.

We are building a web application in JSF and Java for university. Part of it is the upload of a logo, that has got to get stored on a database as a String and  then read from the database again and displayed on the website. The displaying process seems to work just fine but I just can't get the upload working.

This is the .xhtml-Code for the input form on the website:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="i_logo" value="#{systemConfigBean.logo}"
        <f:ajax listener="#{systemConfigBean.upload}" render="@form"/>
    </h:inputFile>
</h:form>
```

The chosen file is read by a `Scanner` in the `upload()` method of the backing bean `systemConfigBean`. The DTO `organisationData`, which is getting passed to the DAO layer has a `byte[]` attribute, into which the logo is stored like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(logo.getInputStream());
String fileContent = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
scanner.close();
organisationData.setLogo(fileContent.getBytes());
```

The DAO converts it into a Base64 String and puts the String onto the database. The String is created like this:

```
String encodedImage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(organisation.getLogo())
```

There has got to be a conversion error up to this point, because the displaying procedure from here works if we just put a Base64 encoded image onto the database. Since we might be wrong and the decoding and displaying might be flawed, this how we handle that part:

In the DAO:

```
organisationData.setLogo(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedImage))
```

In the HTTP-Servelet:

```
response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(""));
response.setContentLength(logo.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(organisationData.getLogo());
```

So my question is, how do we get the conversion right without changing the data type of the DTO attribute `logo` or any other changes to the architecture?

Since this is my very first post on this forum and I always am open for improvement suggestions, please let me know if you have any comments on how I could improve my post.

Comment: Doesn't your DB support blobs? What DB are you using?

Comment: Our DB uses Prostges, but the table in which it is stored only has two columns which are key and value and both are a String.

Comment: Touching the architecture is my least preferred option, because our working force resources are pretty limited and changing the scheme of the database would need a lot of changes elsewhere in the code. Do you think if we just stored the attribute of the DTO into the database it would work as it is?

Comment: Sorry, I was unavailable for most of the day. Well it's very un-typical, at least to my knowledge, to store an image as text. I'm not even sure this is fully supported and it is probably tricky in terms of what encoding to use for writing and reading the image. It may work with some image formats and not with others. It just seems like an unnecessary complication to me, but that's also because I'm unaware of whether those risks really exist or not, I'm just speculating.

Comment: Can you clarify one thing: how exactly did you verify your decoding part worked? If you made it work, you must have used code to convert an image to Base64, so how is that different from your upload logic?

Comment: Absolutely no problem, thank you for your effort.
There is a lot of base64 converters in the internet and we just converted the image and put the String onto the database.

Comment: Then I guess you should start by trying to do the same with code and compare your output with the output the website gave you for the same picture. You can use md5sum to verify they're exactly equal. Just a thing: there are better ways to read a bunch of bytes from a file in memory. Can you know the number of bytes in the image in advance or not?